# Post request does not work on android device

Tags: android, post, ionic3

I've a Ionic v3 application, and when I build it on a android device, all the Http GET request work, but when a POST request is launch, I've got a CORS error...

That's my request:

```
//Headers
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

//Post data
let post_data = {
    my_body: blabla
};
this.http.post(ENV.API_URL + 'test/test', post_data, {headers: headers}).subscribe((data: any) => {

})
```

If anyone can help me?

Comment: can you send the error trace? which error you got when request post.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, you want the HttpErrorResponse?

Comment: yes send that error response or logcat error trace also if possible.

Comment: I've this 'Failed to load http://xxxxxxxx/tasks/review: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.' And httpError: message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"

Comment: I've found the solution, use this plugin cordova-plugin-advanced-http and not @angular/common/http.

Comment: ok congratulations brother.